# Can i execute query in iif function

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I want to know can i run a query in iif function used in ms access database. My case

```
Select field1,(iif(3<4,'Select * from tbl1','select * from tbl2')) from tblmain
```

I am facing syntax error when i try to executed query like that whats the problem

Comment: I wonder if you've simplified out important details, as I have no difficulties using a subselect as the return argument of IIf().

Comment: I could be wrong as I have not used subselects much, but don't your subselects need to link back to your main query with a WHERE clause? If this is the problem, I'll post it as an answer...

Comment: Actually, @Remi, you're right -- I didn't notice that the SELECTs in the question return all rows and all fields. Even if there's only one row and one field, I think it needs to be something more restricted for it to work. When I set up a query like that, I get the error "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word..." If I specify a single field explicitly in the SELECT but don't provide a WHERE clause, I get this error: "At most one record can be returned by the subquery." I had tested a correlated subquery, instead of this mess!

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to achieve isn't clear from your sample query.

You can use IIF functions in Access queries, for example:

```
SELECT IIF([SomeField]<15, "Smaller than 15", "Greater than!") As Whatever 
FROM myTable
```

You can use subselects in Access as well, for example (example shamelessly stolen from http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html):

```
SELECT MeterReading.ID, MeterReading.ReadDate, MeterReading.MeterValue, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.MeterValue                 
     FROM MeterReading AS Dupe                     
     WHERE Dupe.AddressID = MeterReading.AddressID 
         AND Dupe.ReadDate < MeterReading.ReadDate   
     ORDER BY Dupe.ReadDate DESC, Dupe.ID) AS PriorValue 
FROM MeterReading;
```

Note that the specified subselect query must be guaranteed to return a single record - either by specifying TOP 1 or using an aggregate function - and must link back to the parent query in the WHERE clause.

You can't use an IIF statement the way you're trying to in your question, however, even if your subselect was valid, which it is not.

Two options to suggest, although it is less than clear to me what you're trying to achieve here.  First, you might want to consider doing it in VBA instead.  Something like:

```
const query1 As String = "Select * from tbl1"
const query2 As String = "select * from tbl2"

Dim recset as DAO.Recordset
set recset = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(iif(3<4, query1, query2))
```

Alternatively, if both tbl1 and tbl2 had the same fields you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE 3<4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE NOT (3<4)
```

If you replace 3<4 by whatever actual condition you're checking for, you'll only get back records from one or the other or query, never both.  However, my suspicion is that if you need to do this, your database may have design issues - I can think of many questionable scenarios where this would be needed, and few valid ones, although I'm sure they exist.

Comment: Actually, I think it doesn't have to be a correlated subquery as long as it returns 1 field and 1 row. Of course, if it's not correlated with data in each row, it will return the same thing for each row, and you might as well use a DLookup(), or, for that matter, a non-JOINED table in the FROM clause (filtered in the WHERE clause), though the latter would make it noneditable.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the note.